# libGL errors when executing OpenGL program

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opengl

I get this error when I try to execute my program:

```
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

My Code (I took it from the "OpenGL Development Cookbook" book) :

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>

const int WIDTH = 640;
const int HEIGHT = 480;

void OnInit()
{
   glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 0);
   std::cout << "Initialization successfull" << std::endl;
}

void OnShutdown()
{
   std::cout << "Shutdown successfull" << std::endl;
}

void OnResize(int nw, int nh)
{

}

void OnRender()
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
   glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
   glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE | GLUT_DEBUG);
   glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
   glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");

   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   GLenum err = glewInit();

   if(GLEW_OK != err) {std::cerr << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl; }
   else{if(GLEW_VERSION_3_3) {std::cout << "Driver supports OpenGL 3.3\n Details: " << std::endl; }}

   std::cout << "\tUsing glew: " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "\tVendor: " << glGetString(GL_VENDOR) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "\tRenderer: " << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
   std::cout << "\tGLSL: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;

   OnInit();
   glutCloseFunc(OnShutdown);
   glutDisplayFunc(OnRender);
   glutReshapeFunc(OnResize);
   glutMainLoop();
   return 0;
}
```

I verified if my driver supports the OpenGL version I am using with the **glxinfo | grep "OpenGL"** command:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.9
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

I am using **Ubuntu 14.04.3**.

I'm not sure but I think I get this error because I am using **intel** and not **Nvidia**.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from a distance, but the errors you have there look like a damaged OpenGL client library installation. glxinfo queries the GLX driver loaded into the Xorg server, which is somewhat independent from the installed libGL (as long as only indirect rendering calls are made). The errors indicate that the installed libGL either doesn't match the DRI drivers or the DRI libraries are damaged.

Either way, the best course of action is to do a clean reinstall of everything related to OpenGL on your system. I.e. do a forced reinstall of xorg-server, xf86-video-…, mesa, libdri… and so on.

Comment: how do I reinstall them, I just delete and install?

Comment: You're using Ubuntu so I suggest `apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa i965-va-driver libdrm-intel1 xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg libdrm2` that should take care of all packages that participate in Intel graphics.

Comment: I did it and now I get this:

`X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  36
  Current serial number in output stream:  35`
It's not the same as before

Comment: It works, I commented the `glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);` and now it works.Thank you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a very similar error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  42
  Current serial number in output stream:  41
```

Removing the following line solved it:

```
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
```